# Add index from foreach to variable name in fluid

Tags: variables, foreach, typo3, fluid

I got an array :

```
$array = ('picture-1' => '', 'picture-2' => '', 'picture-3' => '');
```

And now i need to use it in fluid like that:

```
<f:for each="{images}" as="image" key="key">
{image.picture-{key}}
</f:for>
```

This is wrong, i'm getting 3 times text {image.picture-{key}}.

How it should be done ?
I know how to do in in php but in fluid i'm newibe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `key`, the `image` variable contains the right data straight away (I've added values to the array):

PHP:

```
$images = array('picture-1' => 'file1.jpg', 'picture-2' => 'file2.jpg', 'picture-3' => 'file3.jpg');
```

Fluid:

```
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
{image} <br />
</f:for>
```

Will result in :

```
file1.jpg <br /> file2 </br /> file3.jpg
```

Comment: OK, but what when my array will looks like this

$array = array(
    1 => array(
      'picture-1-author' => 'name',
      'picture-1-desc' => 'desc',
      'picture-1' => 'file',
    ),
    2 => array(
      'picture-2-author' => 'name',
      'picture-2-desc' => 'desc',
      'picture-2' => 'file',
    ),
    3 => array(
      'picture-3-author' => 'name',
      'picture-3-desc' => 'desc',
      'picture-3' => 'file',
    ),
  );